# Pass Data to other Forms and update Form

Tags: codenameone

In my App, I want users to be able to continuously add Songs to a List in FormA. FormB will then show the added Songs as Labels.

I know how to create the Label-List, but unfortunately, the added Songs won't show up in FormB. I need a way to update FormB every time a Song is added, so FormB is always up-to-date.

This is what I've tried:

```
public void createPlaylist() {
    for (int i = 0; i < songList.getSongList().size(); i++) {
        Button temp = new Button(songList.getSongList().get(i).toString());
        listCont.add(temp); //add Buttons to the List-Container for every Song in the List
    }
    centerCont.removeComponent(listCont); 
    centerCont.removeComponent(bottomCont); //remove Containers to add the updated ones (?)
    centerCont.add(listCont).add(bottomCont); //add updated Containers
}
```

This doesn't work, since the FormB which should show the new added Buttons isn't doing it.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: After adding the songs in FormA, do you press a separate button that takes you to FormB to view all the songs added in FormA? Did you try calling `FormB.revalidate()` after `centerCont.add(listCont).add(bottomCont);`? Where is the code you used to add the songs in FormA? And did you verify that `songList.getSongList()` is not empty?

Comment: Hi, on FormA I press a button to add the songs to the list and then show FormB, the button also calls the function above (createPlaylist). I tried to add the revalidate but i didnt change anything. I log the List in the console and it outputs the Song, so the List seems not to be empty. Do I have to add the centerCont to the Form again as well after adding the listCont to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Diamond Mubaarak, I managed to solve the problem. I just pass the Forms to each other, so I call `FormA.revalidate();` in the FormB Method.